How do we guarantee the result is the global minimizer when dealing a function related to MLE of factor analysis?
I am reading the paper Some contributions to maximum likelihood factor analysis.
Consider the factor analysis model $$y=\Lambda x+z,  $$
where $y$ is a vector containing $p$ features and $x$ is the latent factor vector of length $k<p$.
Let the covariance matrix of $z$ be $\Psi$ and $$\Sigma= \Lambda\Lambda'+\Psi.$$
Let the sample covariance matrix be $S$.
The author said to maximize the log-liklihood function, it suffices to minimize
$$ F_k(\Lambda ,\Psi) =\log|\Sigma|+\text{tr}(S\Sigma^{-1})-\log|S|-p. $$
Then the author solved the equation $\frac{\partial F_k}{\partial \Lambda}=0$,
and concluded that such $\Lambda$ satisfies the columns of $\Psi^{-\frac 12}\Lambda$ are eigenvectors of $\Psi^{-\frac 12}S\Psi^{-\frac 12}$,
and if we choose these eigenvectors to correspond to the $k$ largest eigenvalues,
then the corresponding $F_k$ is smaller than any other selection of eigenvectors.
The author also solved $\frac{\partial F_k}{\partial \Psi}=0$ and got $$ \Psi= \text{diag} (S-\Lambda\Lambda') . $$
The author then said the maximal liklihood estimation for $\Lambda$ and $\Psi$ is the pair determined by the above procedure.
My question is, since we only took the gradient, how do we guarantee for a given $\Psi$, such $\Lambda$ is not a local maxium,
and there is some $\Lambda$ to make $F_k$ smaller (for instance, $F_k\to -\infty$ along some direction) ?
Similar for $\Psi$, how can we make sure for the $\Psi$ determined by the procedure above,
it is not a local maxium of the function $\Psi\mapsto \min F_k(\Lambda,\Psi)$?
The author said this is the MLE, so can we prove this pair of $\Lambda$ and $\Psi$ is the global minimizer of $F_k$?

This post asks a similar problem, but for general MLE. And I think the answer does not solve my confusion.

Likely due to some “regulatity conditions” on the likelihood. One can go further and test and analyze the higher derivatives but I believe there are simplifying assumptions about the maximum being an interior point.

Thanks to DavidR's answer in this post.
Wishart distribution is an exponential family.
Then, as DavidR's answer indicates, in Bickel & Doksum's Mathematical Statistics, Volume 1, 2nd edition, Corollary 1.6.2,
the authors claimed log-likelihood function of canonical exponential family is concave.
Therefore the Hessian matrix $H_{\log q}$ is negative-semidefinite.
When $\Sigma$ is constrained on the subset
$$\Omega=\{\Lambda\Lambda'+\Psi: \Lambda\in\mathbb R^{p\times k},\Psi=\text{diag}(\psi_{11},\cdots,\psi_{pp}),\psi_{ii}>0\},$$
any point that satisfies $\nabla_{\Lambda} \log\text{-likelihood}=0$ would be a local maximizer.
